# Objective-C count for array that was/is a sub array fails?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, count, sub-array

```
NSLog(@"Size of array: %i", ([HistoricDatesArray [23] count]));
HistoricDatesArray [23] = HistoricDatesArray [23][1];
NSLog(@"Size of array: %i", ([HistoricDatesArray [23] count]));
```

As soon as the second NSLog tries to execute:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString count]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x728c7f0'

historicDatesArrray is a NSMutableArray. I can read(NSString) the contents of historicDatesArray[23], but can't count the elements?

I no longer need the object at HistoricDatesArray[23][0] and want to assign the object at HistoricDatesArray[23][1] to HistoricDatesArray[23], which I tested and works, but why can't I use 'count' to get the size of the array?

How can I convert the 2d NSMutableArray back to a 1d NSMutableArray?

Comment: The content of HistoricDatesArray [23][1] seems to be an string, so when you assign it to HistoricDatesArray[23] it ceases to be an array, so, you cant use count on it.

Comment: Patricio. I can count an array that has strings in it and I still treat it as an array. You area correct in assuming they contents of the array are NSString objects, but I doubt the following code would turn it into a string, but then again. I'm the one confused: HistoricDatesArray [23] = HistoricDatesArray [23][1];

Comment: i didn't explain myself well. I mean that after asssignin "HistoricDatesArray [23] = HistoricDatesArray [23][1];" The value of the index 23 in the array HistoricDatesArray is a String and not an Array, before the assigment it was an array and you can count, after it is a String. You can test it with "isKindOfClass"

Comment: You were correct as well Patricio. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that the HistoricDatesArray [23] is no more an array .It is currently holding a string value and It wont have the count property.That makes the issue

**FirstLine**:

Object at HistoricDatesArray index 23 is an Array,It has values as [23][1] ,[23][2]...etc

So you will have value for the count operation

```
NSLog(@"Size of array: %i", ([HistoricDatesArray [23] count]));
```

The value at the HistoricDatesArray [23][1] is a string.

**second Line**:

```
HistoricDatesArray [23] = HistoricDatesArray [23][1];
```

Here you are changing the value of array index [23] from an array to string.and hence there is no more an array at index [23] .It represent a string value

**Third Line**:

```
NSLog(@"Size of array: %i", ([HistoricDatesArray [23] count]));
```

Trying to log the count property where it is for an array,but the value at index 23 is just a string and hence the crash

Comment: He will replace the entire array with the content of HistoricDatesArray [23][1] and only wants to replace HistoricDatesArray [23].

Comment: Patricio you are correct. I absolutely need HistoricDatesArray[23]. I have written a fair amount of code doing some comlex operations and don't really need to count my array, but what's going on? I'm a bit stumped on something so simple. Maybe I'm tired.

Comment: BTW: I need it to stay as an NSMutableArray.

Comment: so I did a:                                                         if ( [downloadedHistoricDatesArray[23] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] ){NSLog(@"Its a string");}
    else {NSLog(@"its not a string");} //and it returned a "Its a string", which is correct the object in the array is NSString, but that doesn't explain why I can't count?

Comment: @ConfusedDeer : see the answer, You will understand what happened